# AnjularJs - should we store objects in $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie to AngularJS. Ho do we manage data from page to page?
1) I have a application where a user logs-in. The database returns the user details. I need to use the user details on other pages. Other pages are not a subset of the login page i.e they have their own scope. So should I store the user in rootScope like $rootScope.user=user. Dumping such data in the rootScope does not look like a good practice. Is there a better way?
2) The 2nd issue is related to the first. If I want to add a $watch on page2 which watches a scope variable on page1, how do I do it.

Comment: As for me, I always store my user information as an **object** in `$rootScope` or a factory. I am not sure whether I should consider this as a best practice, but I feel comfortable doing it this way..

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**Factory**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), And store the necessary login details,

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService', [ '$location','$http', function( $location,$http){
var currentUser;
return {
    login: function(username, password){
        var endPoint = "url";
        var jsonData = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

        $http.post(endPoint, jsonString,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).success(function (data,status, headers ){

            if(data.access == "ok")
            {
                $location.path("learning");
            }
            else
            {
                $location.path("error");
            }

        });
    },
    logout: function(){},
    isLoggedIn: function(){},
    curUser: function(){return currentUser}
};
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9FUSD4LyETI4itmfBtwK?p=info)

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of ideas for your questions:

1) Use Cookies Instead of rooScope, You could also use LocalStorage(Use carefully, It does not work for all explorers)

2) You are looking for emitters and listeners here is a good explanation https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

good luck.

Comment: Your ones are creative, though not the best parctice. If you need to share data, then the Services and Factories are the ones to use in Angular.

Comment: Sajeetharan's answer was the most applicable for my scenario. As I mentioned, our application retrieves data from the database based on user interaction and  the retrieved info needs to be used on multiple pages. Using a factory was the best solution for us. To add further, we created the AuthenticationService in services.js and added it as a dependency to to pages which needed it like:

Comment: app.controller("Controller", '$scope', 'AuthenticationService', function($scope, AuthenticationService){});